# know when a service fabric windows container is being shut down

Tags: containers, azure-service-fabric

I can't see any options in the VS project to add any code logic to determine when a container is being shutdown/moved in service fabric.
The only thing I can see this work, would be to have a reliable service in the container, and then override the `OnCloseAsync()`

Does this sound right/feasible? Are reliable services, in windows containers, available yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a [service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-services-inside-containers) inside a container. This features is currently in preview.

Another way that may work is to register a [notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient.servicemanagementclient.registerservicenotificationfilterasync) callback for endpoint changes. When a service is moved, or removed, its endpoint changes.

Comment: Ta for the link to running services in the container. Good idea on the endpoint changes, but I need to do some "cleanup" in the container before it is shut if possible.